# DEVOPS: Express and Mongo Docker Container Networking

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have been writing [this awesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh0ui.png) Express & MongoDB app, just for fun, 
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh0ui.png): https://github.com/mwaz/oober-bck, everything is working perfectly offline, I have different DB configurations for different application environments e.g, development, staging, testing, and production, in the real sense in every environment, the DB is different and given MongoDB is flexible, we do not have a problem with that.

Since the Application is working normally by setting the $NODE_ENV variable to the application environment required on my local machine, everything should work fine when the application is dockerized, however this is not the case, the mongoDB crashes at some point and does not connect to the application, here is the sample log 
[image: Docker Log, when running docker-compose up]

The Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node app.js
EXPOSE 3003
```

The docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: oober
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3003:3003"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=STAGING
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

The docker image can be found on dockerhub using this link

```
docker pull sparatan/oober_app
```

Comment: @DavidMaze Express Js connects to the Database from a server file, in the above, it is located in the GitHub repository link goes by the name app.js in the  application folder

Comment: I'd also appreciate if someone left comments rather than downvoting because you did not understand the question or you did not feel like the question was asked correctly according to your expertise or knowledge

Comment: @DavidMaze To reproduce: pull the container from docker-hub, using docker pull sparatan/oober_app, spin up the application using docker-compose up,
I only included what was relevant, it is a DevOps issue and therefore I only attached the docker configuration files, that is relevant and does not require you to dig into my GitHub repository. , what other details need to be included, kindly clarify. The application is fine, the configuration is the problem

Answer (score 3):

Your default configuration of the staging database is `DATABASE: "mongodb://localhost:27017/staging_ooberdb"` as shown in your [config.js](https://github.com/mwaz/oober-bck/blob/master/config.js) file.

In a docker environment as you're using "localhost" will refer to the container itself (in this case your "oober" container.

You need to use the mongodb container name instead like this `DATABASE: "mongodb://mongo:27017/staging_ooberdb"` in the STAGING part of your config.js file.

As a side note, you probably don't want to expose the mongodb port in a production environment.

Comment: The config file just has variables for configurations, getting to the values, I just get the values in the objects e.g config[process.env.NODE_ENV]['DATABASE'];

in the file config.js, i have several environments and they each have a configuration, the problem is not that the application does not work, it even connects in the container, kindly refer to the log above

Comment: kindly go through: https://github.com/mwaz/oober-bck/blob/master/config.js and 
https://github.com/mwaz/oober-bck/blob/master/app.js

You might understand a thing or two, about how the app runs and the environment variables, The env variable NODE_ENV, carries all the configuration for that particualar environment

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. I did look through it and my answer is still valid. Doesn't it work?

Comment: All i want is an explanation why, MongoDB, starts inside the container then crashes, and how that can be resolved, in my thoughts it might be a networking issue, but not a configuration issue, as both the app and the mongoDB container start when the app spins up

Comment: Mongodb is not crashing. Your oober container is crashing because it cannot connect to your mongodb. It IS a configuration issues because of how docker networking works. [This blog post](https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/understanding-docker-networking-drivers-use-cases/) from docker might help. Basically each container have their own IP address/hostname so localhost will always refer to "itself" and you should connect containers using their hostname (which is also the container name).

Comment: let me read on this, this kind-off points me to the right direction

Comment: Modifying the staging URL to `mongodb` instead of  `localhost` actually works, thanks